# How do you become friends with someone?

Tags: overwatch

Let's say I'm playing in a public game with someone and we hit it off. I want to officially become his friend, so that we can intentionally group later on. How do I do this?

I know how to find the list of recent players. I know how to find the list of people currently on my team. But in neither place does there seem to be a context option to become friends with that person.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but how do you invite someone you've played Overwatch with to become friends?

Comment: Will this differ between platforms? For example, a console's UI may offer functionality over and above the game (Xbox 360, for example, lets you see a list of the players you have recently played with, allowing you to add them as a friend/report or message easier... maybe the same is possible for the Xbox One, not that I noticed).

Comment: I think unfortunately at the moment the only way to become friends with someone is to whisper to him and ask for his battle.net name (name + hashtag-number, i.e. Max#1234).

Comment: Awwwww, titles.

Comment: Dammnit, I thought this would help me IRL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure about console but on PC at the top of your friends list there is a 'Recent players' tab.

If you right click on a person you will see an 'Add friend' option in the dialog menu which, provided that they accept the request, adds them to your battle.net friends list.

[image: Example]

You can also right click on a person's name in chat and add them that way (as pointed out by GnomeSlice below).

Comment: You can also bring up the in-game chat and right click on their name if they've posted a message.

Comment: Does this add them to friends in Overwatch, Battle.net or both?

Comment: @David I've updated the answer

Comment: I swear I looked there, but I'll double-check again when I get home.

Comment: The process is similar on Xbox Live. You check recent players and 'Add Friend'. Unfortunately, for some reason, they've made this asymmetric on Xbox One. Adding someone as a friend makes them your friend, but does not make you theirs. They have to add you as well. I'm not positive, but I don't think you can join their game without an invite until they add you as well.

Comment: @DCShannon I believe that is not correct. It does send a request.

Comment: @ardaozkal It notifies them that you have added them as a friend, which gives them the opportunity to do the same, but even if they don't also add you as a friend, you've still added them.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

On xbox you have to press menu, then 'social' then tab across to 'recent players' from select the game person you want then hit 'view gamercard' the you will see 'add friend' etc. They will then appear in your friend's list on xbox and in overwatch